# Using Beautiful Soup to parse top-level XML channel tag only

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to create a graceful way to parse XML news feeds.

1. Primarily, use the `<channel>` / `<pudDate>` header

   - **NOTE:** Not `pubDate` from the nested `<item>`'s, but rather the single `<channel>` **header**
2. Secondarily, use the `<channel>` / `<lastBuildDate>` header
3. Lastly, use the max timestamp of `<item>` / `<pubDate>`

**Tried:**

```py
def get_xml(url):
        try:
            header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
            request = urllib.request.Request(url=url, headers=header)
            response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
            bsoup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'xml')
            return bsoup
        except:
            logging.error(f'Invalid URL: {url}')
            return None

def get_xml_file(bsoup_obj, source):
        
        if bsoup_obj.find('channel').find('pubDate'):
            pubDate = bsoup_obj.find('channel').pubDate.text
        
        elif bsoup_obj.find('channel').find('lastBuildDate'):
            pubDate = bsoup_obj.find('channel').lastBuildDate.text
        
        else:
            all_pubDates = bsoup_obj.findAll('pubDate')
            ts = []
            for a in all_pubDates:
                formatted_ts = datetime.strptime(a.text, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z')
                test.append(formatted_ts)
            pubDate = max(ts)

        data = {
            "source": source,
            "pub_date": pubDate,
            "xml_doc": str(bsoup_obj),
            "created": datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
        }
        return data
```

**Also tried:**

- `if bsoup_obj.find('channel')['pubDate']:`
- `if bsoup_obj.find('channel/pubDate')`

**Issue:**

- I can't find the syntax to search ONLY THE HEADER `<channel>` / `<pubDate>`!
- The above pulls the `item` / `pubDate`

[image]

Comment: `bsoup_obj.select_one('channel > pubDate')` should work (?)

Comment: That worked! Thank you! Where is this documented?

Comment: this is a [`css selector`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: Hm. Interesting since this is parsing XML which (I believe) has no CSS. (Edited the original post to show the xml parser)

Comment: [Here](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#css-selectors) is the BS4 doc covering this syntax.

Comment: @diggusbickus, unfortunate this doesn't work with `find_all()`. Example. If the XML doc has `pubDate` at the `channel` level and the `item` level, there is no way tell `find_all('channel > item')`

Comment: instead of `select_one` use `select`...

Comment: I'll try. `select` does not allow `.text` to read the plaintext. `select_one().text` makes that easy. Maybe `select().get_text()` works.